# Basic Javascript if/else - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I've been racking my brain for a couple hours and I'm stuck, anyone have anything for me? What am I doing wrong?

```
  function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
  let lovesPizza;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: typeOfPizza
  // You are also given another variable called: lovesPizza;
  // Using an if/else statement assign lovesPizza to true if typeOfPizza is 'pepperoni', assign it to false if it is 'olives'



if (typeOfPizza === 'pepperoni');
  lovesPizza = true;
  } else {
  (typeOfPizza === 'olives');
  lovesPizza = false;
  }
  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return lovesPizza;
}
```

Comment: `else { (typeOfPizza === 'olives'); lovesPizza = false; }` -> `else if (typeOfPizza === 'olives') { lovesPizza = false; }`

Comment: Try removing the semi colon after the test ( typeOfPiza === 'olives' )

Comment: Your curly brackets don't add up, there are semicolons after your conditions which shouldn't be there and an `else` with an additional condition should be an `else if (condition)`.

Answer (score 1):

it's just your "if" syntax

```js
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
    let lovesPizza;
    // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: typeOfPizza
    // You are also given another variable called: lovesPizza;
    // Using an if/else statement assign lovesPizza to true if typeOfPizza is 'pepperoni', assign it to false if it is 'olives'



    if (typeOfPizza === 'pepperoni'){
        lovesPizza = true;
    } else if (typeOfPizza === 'olives') {
        lovesPizza = false;
    }

    // Please write your answer in the line above.
    return lovesPizza;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a semicolon in the wrong place on your if statements. For a basic if statement, the semicolon only goes after the lines in the code block to be executed if the condition is true (the part between the curly braces), not after the condition itself:

```
if (condition) { //no semicolon
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true - semicolon here
}
```

So your code basically has 2 extra semicolons and 2 closing curly braces without matching opening braces. Try this for your code:

```
  function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
  let lovesPizza;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: typeOfPizza
  // You are also given another variable called: lovesPizza;
  // Using an if/else statement assign lovesPizza to true if typeOfPizza is 'pepperoni', assign it to false if it is 'olives'



if (typeOfPizza === 'pepperoni'){
  lovesPizza = true;
  } else if (typeOfPizza === 'olives'){
  lovesPizza = false;
  }
  
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return lovesPizza;
}
```

You can check out this page for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else